# Host an app at home location of Shiny server

Tags: shiny-server

I installed my Shiny server and it is working fine with multiple app under this directory:

/srv/shiny-server/app1
/srv/shiny-server/app2

I can use www.mydomain.com/app1  to access my app.

But when I use www.mydomain.com it shows the default shiny server app with the example app.

All I want is when I go to www.mydomain.com I can see app1, how can I make that happen?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer mentioned, you can edit the `location`construct of `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf`.

Remove or comment out the `site_dir` and `directory_index` lines. Leave the `log_dir` line -- a `log_dir` is required within your first `location` construct. Add an `app_dir` line with the path to your app.

This works with the sample apps:

1) Remove the `index.html` file from `/srv/shiny-server/`

2) Edit the `location` section of `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` to look like this:

```
location / {
    # Host app at base directory
    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/hello;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from: http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/

modify your /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf

```
server {
  ...
  # Define the location '/specialApp'
  location /specialApp {
    # Run this location in 'app_dir' mode, which will host a single Shiny
    # Application available at '/srv/shiny-server/myApp'
    app_dir /srv/shiny-server/myApp
  }

  # Define the location '/otherApps'
  location /otherApps {
    # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
    # tree at '/srv/shiny-server/apps'
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server/apps;
  }
...
}
```